# How to navigate from Appdelegate to another viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

In my iPhone app, I am using Pushnotifications. When I receive a notification, I want to move to another viewcontroller from the current viewcontroller. I wrote the `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` in the appdelegate itself. And I am using View based application, so I want to use `presentModalViewController` (i think). And I used following code:

```
UIViewController *view = (UIViewController*)self.viewController.presentedViewController;
                [view presentModalViewController:self.anotherVC animated:NO];
```

but got error

```
2012-06-19 17:47:52.521 iPhoneApp[1450:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <HomeScreenVC: 0x1fb77cc0>.'
```

what went wrong here? Any idea.

**Edit**
I will elaborate the issue:
I have viewcontrollers VC1, VC2, VC3 and VC4. My rootviewcontroller is VC1. If a push notification come when I am at VC2 or VC4, when I click on Ok button of notification alert, I want to move to VC3. But the delegate method for the alert view is in appdelegate.m.

I have updated my code like

```
        self.menuVC = [[MenuScreenVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuScreenVC" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *view = (UIViewController*)self.viewController.presentedViewController;
        [view presentModalViewController:self.menuVC animated:NO];
```

now I can navigate to VC3 if i am at VC2, I can't if i am at VC4. Please help

Answer (score 3):

Instead of what you used do the following

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:self.anotherVC animated:NO];
```